# Show when column exceeds vertical axis maximum

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I've built a stacked clustered column in Excel 2016. I've manually set the maximum value of the vertical axis and several of the (combined) columns overflow. I want to provide some visual indication that the columns exceed the threshold, for example: a + symbol on top of these bars, or, the combined value of the grey/yellow parts.

[image: clustered stacked column chart currently]

Answer (score 3):

assuming your data is in columns `B` and `C`

1. Insert the following formula in `D`:

   ```
   =IF(SUM(B2:C2)>2500, "+","")
   ```

And populate down

2. Add a label to a series, then right-click on it and choose "Format Data Labels"
3. Under "Label Contains", check "Value From Cells" and select the range in column `D` with the formula and uncheck everything else.

[image]

4. You will probably want to choose "Inside base" for the label position

Your chart will then look something like this:

[image]

NB: If you want the total value instead of `+` signs, then use `=IF(SUM(B2:C2)>2500, SUM(B2:C2),"")` as your formula in `D`

Comment: Thank you. Do you know a way to bring the + symbol to above the upper major unit line (10 in your example's case)?

Comment: You can manually move them there, but AFAIK, there is no way to automatically do this